# Calling method after checking its existence given error instead of warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i am calling a method after checking its existence but it is keep giving the error. i am doing all this stuff many times but now it is giving error. any Help

```
 if ([[self.navDashBoard.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(updateScreenForExtraOption)])
    {
        [[self.navDashBoard.viewControllers lastObject] updateScreenForExtraOption];
    }
```

---

PLEASE see my updated image same thing works perfectly at the same class and other method does not. I had not make any Category or ViewController subclass that has refreshPage method in it.

[image]

Comment: `respondsToSelector` is evaluated at runtime. The error you are receiving is from the compiler telling you that, as far as it knows, this line of code is going to crash at runtime. Assuming that your method is implemented by a UIViewController subclass then you should cast the view controller object to an appropriately typed variable and then check isKindOfClass or respondsToSelector at runtime

Comment: please see my update image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually what you see is this:

```
 if ([[self.navDashBoard.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(updateScreenForExtraOption)])
 {
     [[self.navDashBoard.viewControllers lastObject] performSelector:@selector(updateScreenForExtraOption)];
 }
```

This will give a warning but not a error while calling the method directly will. Or do it the way Paulw11 suggested and cast it to the right type.

Answer (score 0):

i just fixed this issue by importing a class(UIViewController subclass) that has this method declare as public. even i am not using that class.

Comment: This makes very little sense as an answer. Please provide a more detailed answer so if anyone else has the issue in the future they can resolve it

Comment: So what you have done is imported a class so that the selector is at least known to the compiler - The error it was giving you was that it had never heard of the selector you were using.   Your code is still 'dodgy'

Comment: so do you recommend  me that i should not use this technique? i have a navigation controller on which i need to check current visible view controller and need to call a method if exists in it.